# Building a 24h visualisation with chartjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to build a custom chart using chartjs, but I couldn't find the right documentation that explains how dataset works.

I am trying to build a 24 hours timebar that contains different blocks stacked next to each other **with different colors for each** (ie: bars to represent the activity with start & end date)

[image: A bad drawing of the result requested]

with the current options object I couldn't achieve the goal required.

> [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chartjs-app-xb6lfi?file=components/Timebar.js)

```
    new Chart(myChartRef, {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: {
        labels: [
          "no-shift",
          "in",
          "work",
          "out",
          "absence",
          "leave"
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Attendance",
            data:[
            [new Date("2021-08-11T00:00:00"),new Date("2021-08-11T08:00:00")],
            [new Date("2021-08-11T08:00:00"),new Date("2021-08-11T08:01:00")],
            [new Date("2021-08-11T10:00:00"),new Date("2021-08-11T10:05:00")],
            [new Date("2021-08-11T10:00:00"),new Date("2021-08-11T12:00:00")],
            [new Date("2021-08-11T12:00:00"),new Date("2021-08-11T10:05:00")],
            ],
            backgroundColor: "rgb(220,20,60)"
          },
        ]
      },
      options: {
        //Customize chart options
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                format: 'HH:mm',
                unit: 'minute',
                unitStepSize: 1,
                displayFormats: {
                  minute: 'HH:mm',
                  hour: 'HH:mm',
                  min: '00:00',
                  max: '23:59'
                }
              },
              display: true,
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Time'
              }
            }
          ],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
              min: 0,
              max: 1,
              stepSize: 1
            }
        }]
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I used the "chartjs-chart-timeline" plugin for cases like this. It worked quite well, but you should know it hasn't been updated for a while and it still uses chartjs v2. I haven't tested it with chartjs v3 yet. It may not be the best solution. If you really need it, I can have a deeper look at it and may write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @HeadhunterKev for the reply;

based on this issue : [chartjs](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6317), I couldn't find anything in chartjs that can lead to the desired chart.

If you need to build something like such, react google charts can do the trick [documentation](https://react-google-charts.com/timeline-chart).

Answer (score 1):

You can use floating bars together with the datalabels plugin and a stacked y axis to achieve what you want:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels)

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'working',
        data: [
          [new Date('2021-09-18T04:00:00'), new Date('2021-09-18T20:30:00')],
          [new Date('2021-09-18T06:00:00'), new Date('2021-09-18T17:00:00')]
        ],
        backgroundColor: "red",
      },
      {
        label: 'sleep',
        data: [
          [new Date('2021-09-18T00:00:00'), new Date('2021-09-18T04:00:00')],
          [new Date('2021-09-18T00:00:00'), new Date('2021-09-18T06:00:00')],
          [new Date('2021-09-18T00:00:00'), new Date('2021-09-18T06:00:00')]
        ],
        backgroundColor: "blue",
      },
      {
        label: 'sleeping',
        data: [
          [new Date('2021-09-18T20:30:00'), new Date('2021-09-18T23:59:59')],
          [new Date('2021-09-18T17:00:00'), new Date('2021-09-18T23:59:59')],
          [new Date('2021-09-18T17:00:00'), new Date('2021-09-18T23:59:59')]
        ],
        backgroundColor: "orange",
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    indexAxis: 'y',
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      datalabels: {
        color: 'white',
        formatter: (val, ctx) => (ctx.dataset.label)
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true
      },
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          // Luxon format string
          tooltipFormat: 'DD'
        },
        min: new Date('2021-09-18T00:00:00'),
        max: new Date('2021-09-18T23:59:59')
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="chart-view">
  <canvas id="chart" width="600" height="200" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for submitting this answer, it will be a reference for others looking to create a similar behavior like the one I mentioned. After running the code snippet it was close to what I was creating but less souple if you know what I mean. also comparing the code with react google charts, is much messier for juniors to maintain thus defeating my purpose :). all in all thanks :)